# how to @ youself and someone else in a embed on discord

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Here is my code. It works but I don't kno how to make it mention someone.

When I do `!call @someone` it does not mention them, it mentiona me.

```
if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "call" )){
message.channel.send('Love UwU');
}
if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "call" )){
   var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
         .setTitle(message.author.toString() + 'called' + message.author.toString())
         .setTimestamp()
         .setImage('https://ii.yuki.la/7/29/012c95f665ec8cc105e45d31e1eb347eb74bdfb603f0ab37a86392fff9d78297.gif')
     message.channel.send(embed);
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please keep your swear word commands for your final implementation. We don't need them here.

Comment: You're lucky it got edited rather than deleted. Please avoid rampant profanity. It downvoted and/or flagged

Comment: sorry I'm new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the result you get because you use the same code at two places.

```
message.author.toString() + 'called' + message.author.toString()
    ^ once here                            ^ and once here
```

What you need to do is get the member you mentioned and use that instead.

```
message.mentions.members.first().toString()
```

Comment: like this?     .setTitle(message.mentions.members.first().toString() + 'called' +message.author.toString())